# Calling a WebMethod using jQueryAjax "GET"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

i have a ajax request which works well using "POST" but when used "GET" it gives me the following error,

```
{"Message":"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027GetSomething\u0027 
using a GET      request, which is not allowed.","StackTrace":" at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData 
methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, 
WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

so here is my code, on the client side,

```
function test() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default4.aspx/GetSomething",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) { debugger; alert(res.d); },
            error: function (res) { debugger; alert("error"); }
        });
    }
```

on the server side,

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSomething()
{
    return "got something";
}
```

any reason why i am getting error when used "GET" ??

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to invoke it using GET, you need to add:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
....
```

Comment: I was suffering from same issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another Ways: You can add it in config File

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
              <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Both options are fine: to decorate with  `ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true) ` and also to (case sensitive) add `webServices' entry on webconfig

Answer (score 1):

you should add the following code before the  tag in Web .config file.

```
<location path="webservice.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</location>
```