# Ajax call not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call to C# function but it is not being call.

This is ajax call:

```
$('#button1 button').click(function () {
    var username = "username_declared";
    var firstname = "firstname_declared";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "practiced_final.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
        data:{username1:username,firstname1:firstname},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert(a + b + c);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ServerSideMethod(string username1, string firstname1)
{
    return "Message from server with parameter." + username1 + "hello" + firstname1;
}
```

This method is not getting hit and shows a error message like this:

```
object XMLHttpRequest]parsererrorundefined
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would start by using Fiddler to inspect the data that's sent and received.

Comment: Besides using Fiddler to inspect the request, you can also open it in your browser and see Error-Messages from IIS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button1 button').live('click', function () {
            var username = "username_declared";
            var firstname = "firstname_declared";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/practiced_final.aspx/ServerSideMethod", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ username1: username, firstname1: firstname }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(a + b + c);
                }
            });
        });
```

**$('button#button1') or $('#button1') or $('#button1 button')** 
check u selector also. put one alert message inside click event  and see

Comment: it didn't work,but now the error is disappeared.C# method still didn't get a hit

Comment: selector is fine.i checked it using alert box.

Comment: k. you r using mvc 3 or asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Finally it is working.This is the final code.
Thanks everyone for your wise replies.

```
                $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "practiced_final.aspx/hello_print",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (msg) {
                 $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                 }
                 })
                 return false;
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
data:{username1:username,firstname1:firstname},
```

to

```
data:JSON.stringify({username1:username,firstname1:firstname}),
```

Edit:

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but this is one thing I noticed different between our jQuery ajax calls. Also, changed result string to reflect @dana's criticism in the comments of my answer.

Comment: User input should be escaped using `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Is this just to make the ajax call less prone to error or is there more reasoning behind `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: Think about the case where: `var firstname = "D'Angelo"`.  The single quote needs to be escaped with a backslash to create a valid JSON string: `D\'Angelo`.  `JSON.stringify()` takes care of that case and many others.

Comment: That is good to know. I did not know about `JSON.stringify()` prior to your comment, so thanks for the information. I will edit my answer, although it seems mine wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can see : dataType: "json",

But you're not sending a Json through your C# function... When you're telling ajax that the dataType is a json, it will JSON.parse() the response. Maybe that's where the failure is.
Try changing the dataType, or removing it (jQuery will try to guess it).

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('button#button1') //Or check selector put one alert inside onclick
  $('#button1').live('click', function () {
                var username = "username_declared";
                var firstname = "firstname_declared";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "practiced_final.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ username1: username, firstname1: firstname }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function (a, b, c) {
                        alert(a + b + c);
                    }
                    })
                    return false;
```

it may help

Comment: it didn't work,but now the error is disappeared.C# method still didn't get a hit.

Comment: :) k gud i will look for it may i get something in sometime

Comment: User input should be escaped using `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @ThulasiRam
same issue.No error but method  couldn't hit...:(
btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change below line in Jquery function.

data:{username1:username,firstname1:firstname},

to

data:"{'username1':'" + username + "','firstname1':'" + firstname + "'}",

Hope this will help you.

Comment: User input should be escaped using `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: please change Type Get to POST.

Comment: Yes changing it to post is working.can you please tell me why GET didn't work
Thank you.

Comment: hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750631/calling-a-webmethod-using-jqueryajax-get