# Call web service using json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asmx, service-reference

I have two projects:

ASP.net web site project:

Default.aspx

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

   function DisplayMessageCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:24218/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccessCall,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });
}
function OnSuccessCall(response) {
    $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(response.d);
}

function OnErrorCall(response) {
    alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
}

 </script>

  <h2>Example 1: Call Webservice using JQuery AJax (Without Input)</h2>

<asp:Button ID="btnGetMsg" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="DisplayMessageCall();return false;" /><br />

<asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

And ASP Web Service Application:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I added in my ASP web site the reference for my webService but when I click on the button I get the error message. 
When I enter the url

```
                  (http://localhost:24218/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld)
```

in the browser I get the following result:

```
          <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

I use ASP.NET 4.5.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've configured a GET method instead of a POST method. If you switch your $ajax call to:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      . . .
```

then it may work

Comment: It doesn't work where do I configure the GET or the POST method?

Comment: Is it normal that I get an XML result when I click on the URL: <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string> ?

Comment: Yes that's normal. You would need
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)] ( see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10752837/275501 )

Comment: I added [WebMethod][ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)] and it work's just fine if I have my web service located in my web site, but when I call the webservice located in another webservices project it doesn't work. Did I miss something after adding the service reference??

Comment: You shouldn't need a web reference at all if you're calling it from javascript. What is the error you get when it's located in another web services project?

Comment: responseText return an empty string!!

Comment: perhaps this is a same-origin policy problem? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: I have tried to launch my application in different browsers but still the same problem responseText return an empty string

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are loading, and the URL of the web service?

Comment: The url of the page is:                                                          http://localhost:22394/WebSite/Default.aspx                                     The url of the web service is:                                                       http://localhost:29265/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld

Comment: Yes, you can't go from one port (22394) to another (29265). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery

Comment: Ok, another question please. Is there a way to run my two applications using the same port?

Comment: not from visual studio as far as i know. Either configure them as virtual applications in IIS, or use JSONP